# Blender Geometry Nodes: Extrude faces based on curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, extrude

I want to extrude faces along a curve. I dont want them to extrude with a fixed length, but with a  length based on where the faces are located on the curve. I want the faces on the start of the curve (left) to extrude only slightly and extrude more towards the end (right side). Basically the same effect i did on the curve with the spline parameter (factor).
I appreciate any suggestions!

[image: This is my current node setup]

[image: The image shows what i achieved so far and what I want to achieve (white lines)]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can capture the factor value on the main curve (with either a `Capture Attribute` or `Store Named Attribute`) like you did with the profile curve, and feed that into the *Offset Scale* of the `Extrude Mesh` node:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way

[image]

You need to put the factor in the offset scale (You have it plugged into the selection socket)

With a math node set to multiply, you can control the strength of the scale

You could also use a map range to control where the extrusion starts